# How to join (merge) data frames by different variables for each observation

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, left-join

Suppose I have two data frames like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    X = c(1,2,2),
    Y = c("a","b","c"),
    Z = c(10,20,30)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  X = c(1,2,2,4),
  Y = c(NA,"b","c","d"),
  W = c(-1,-2,-3,-4)
)
```

I would like to left join df1 on df2 using both X and Y. But for the first observation I'd only use X. In the end I'd like to get:

```
df3 <- data.frame(
  X = c(1,2,2,4),
  Y = c(NA,"b","c","d"),
  W = c(-1,-2,-3,-4),
  Z = c(10,20,30,NA)
)
```

Couldn't do it using left_join or full_join.

Comment: Is that your real code? You're missing a comma in `df3`.

Comment: When you say the 'first' observation, is it based on the `by` variable on both dataset

Comment: Not my real code. Included the comma in `df3`

Comment: If the _second_ element of `df2$Y` is `NA`, what is your expected output? (what would Z be?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps. First, left join df2 on df1 using X and Y. Second, replace any missing value in Z with the corresponding value in df1 based on X only. But this will only work if there are no duplicates in X.

```
df4 <- merge(df2, df1, all.x=TRUE); df4
#  X    Y  W  Z
#1 1 <NA> -1 NA # <-- this guy could not match, since Y was NA
#2 2    b -2 20
#3 2    c -3 30
#4 4    d -4 NA

ind <- df4$X[is.na(df4$Z)] # returns the indices 1 4
df4$Z[ind] <- df1$Z[ind]
df4
#  X    Y  W  Z
#1 1 <NA> -1 10
#2 2    b -2 20
#3 2    c -3 30
#4 4    d -4 NA
```

If df2$Y contains NA for any X that is duplicated, then the solution is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant-looking, but I don't know how to do (well) conditional joins:

```r
full_join(df2, df1, by = c("X", "Y")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(W)) %>%
  group_by(grp = is.na(Y)) %>%
  do({
    dat <- .
    if (is.na(dat$Y[1])) {
      left_join(dat, select(df1, -Y), by = "X") %>%
        mutate(Z = coalesce(Z.x, Z.y)) %>%
        select(-starts_with("Z."))
    } else dat
  }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  arrange(X, Y)
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#       X Y         W     Z
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 <NA>     -1    10
# 2     2 b        -2    20
# 3     2 c        -3    30
# 4     4 d        -4    NA
```